# Dimple line chart in Chrome does not draw correctly when more than 10 data pairs

Tags: google-chrome, dimple.js

I have created a jsfiddle that will allow you to see my problem.  The problem only occurs in Chrome.  Latest versions of Safari, IE, FF work perfectly.  Is this a known issue?  Is there a fix?  D3 without Dimple works fine.  Any thoughts or knowledge of a work around would be great.

http://jsfiddle.net/ernieb0y/0ovteqr8/1/

`   var data1 = [{"distance":"31","variance":0.11},
         {"distance":"92","variance":0.38},
         {"distance":"153","variance":0.84},
         {"distance":"214","variance":1.55},
         {"distance":"276","variance":2.34},
         {"distance":"337","variance":3.04},
         {"distance":"398","variance":3.86},
         {"distance":"459","variance":4.6},
         {"distance":"521","variance":5.16},
         {"distance":"582","variance":6.09},
        ]
    var data2 = [{"distance":"31","variance":0.11},
             {"distance":"92","variance":0.38},
             {"distance":"153","variance":0.84},
             {"distance":"214","variance":1.55},
             {"distance":"276","variance":2.34},
             {"distance":"337","variance":3.04},
             {"distance":"398","variance":3.86},
             {"distance":"459","variance":4.6},
             {"distance":"521","variance":5.16},
             {"distance":"582","variance":6.09},
             {"distance":"643","variance":6.89},
            ]

```
var svg = dimple.newSvg("#chartContainer", 600,600);

  var myChart = new dimple.chart(svg);
  myChart.setBounds(90, 35, 480, 400)
  xAxis = myChart.addMeasureAxis("x", "distance");
  yAxis = myChart.addMeasureAxis("y", "variance");
  xAxis.showGridlines = true;
  yAxis.ticks = 5 
  xAxis.ticks = 5 
  s1 = myChart.addSeries(["distance","perf_1"], dimple.plot.line, [xAxis, yAxis]);
  s1.data = data1
  s1.lineMarkers = true;
  s2 = myChart.addSeries(["distance","perf_2"], dimple.plot.line, [xAxis, yAxis]);
  s2.data = data2
  myChart.addLegend(90, 480, 330, 20, "left");
  myChart.draw();`
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with the data, but with the addSeries calls.  I've adjusted them here:

see fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jose_jimenez/nvrekzd5/1/

when you pass an array ['distance','perf1'] it expects each to be a column, it has the side effect of creating a legend.

if you want to have two series with similar axes, you could just add a column to your data set (field name perf, values 'perf1', 'perf2') which would then give you something like you want.

http://jsfiddle.net/jose_jimenez/nvrekzd5/2/

(adjusted to have slightly different values for illustration purposes)

```
var data1 = [{"perf": 'perf1', "distance":"31","variance":0.11},
     {"perf": 'perf1', "distance":"92","variance":0.38},
     {"perf": 'perf1', "distance":"153","variance":0.84},
     {"perf": 'perf2', "distance":"31","variance":0.12},
         {"perf": 'perf2', "distance":"94","variance":0.38},
         {"perf": 'perf2', "distance":"150","variance":0.87},
         ]

var svg = dimple.newSvg("#chartContainer", 600,600);

  var myChart = new dimple.chart(svg);
  myChart.setBounds(90, 35, 480, 400)
  xAxis = myChart.addMeasureAxis("x", "distance");
  yAxis = myChart.addMeasureAxis("y", "variance");
  xAxis.showGridlines = true;
  yAxis.ticks = 5 
  xAxis.ticks = 5 
  s1 = myChart.addSeries(["distance", 'perf'], dimple.plot.line, [xAxis, yAxis]);
  s1.data = data1
  s1.lineMarkers = true;
  myChart.addLegend(90, 480, 330, 20, "left");
  myChart.draw();
```